# How do you maximize a window using KDE?

Tags: kde, kde-4, kde-plasma-workspace

That is my monitor configuration:

[image: My monitor configuration]

By clicking `(^)` the window maximizes into a single monitor.

**Oct 7, 2015 8:29 UTC:** How do people configure X11 to see all displays as a single display?

**Oct 7, 2015 10:04 UTC:**

```
$ lspci && xrandr
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (
rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PC
I Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family U
SB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipse
t Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V (rev 
05)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family U
SB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Defin
ition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI E
xpress Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI E
xpress Root Port #2 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family U
SB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation C220 Series Chipset Family H81 Express LP
C Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 
6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Cont
roller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 [GeForce GT 720] (r
ev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0e0f (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac 
PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2400 x 1920, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 connected 1200x1920+0+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 
518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+  59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.97    60.05    
60.00    50.04  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00
   1152x864      75.00
   1024x768      75.03    60.00
   800x600       75.00    60.32
   720x576       50.00    50.08
   720x480       59.94    60.05
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93
HDMI-0 connected 1200x1920+1200+0 right (normal left inverted right x axis y ax
is) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+  59.88           
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.97    60.05   
60.00    50.04                             
   1600x1200     60.00                                
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02                        
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00          
   1152x864      75.00         
   1024x768      75.03    60.00       
   800x600       75.00    60.32         
   720x576       50.00    50.08             
   720x480       59.94    60.05         
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93    
$ _
```

My 'Kate->Help->About KDE' tells 'Platform Version 4.14.2'.

Comment: Commenting because I don't know the actual answer, but you need to configure X11 to see all four monitors as one large display. The maximize button will then work as you want it to.

Comment: Maybe it can be helpful to add your current video driver and monitor specifications...

Comment: I can't remember what its called but it should be something like xinerama or something that makes multiple screens look like a single display. I'd answer but I don't know the *exact* way to set that up, or if its even supported.

Comment: And my question is: how do I maximise into a single window? :-). I attached an external display (HP-ZR2440w) to a ThinkPad 14" (Intel HD Graphics 4400), and used the following command to get, more or less satisfying, an extented display: `xrandr --output eDP1 --primary --mode 2560x1440 --pos 0x1440 --rotate normal  --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1200 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --scale 1.333333x1.333333`. Each time a maximise a window, it spans across both screens. I want the opposite.